# How should one go about learning discrete mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, learning

- How should one go with learning the proofs?
- How should one learn to prove things themselves?
- What kind of thinking skills should one develop and how?
- How should one practice problems? How to remember the concepts one learnt  better?
- All in all, what should be the main strategy to do full justice to discrete mathematics and enjoy it.

Comment: Take a textbook, study it, learn the proofs, try the exercises... ["There is no royal road"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Euclid#Attributed) to Discrete Mathematics.

Comment: You learn it bit by bit, in discrete steps.

Comment: Finite Mathematics, by Kemeny, Snell, and Thompson.

Comment: Start with proofs by natural induction.

Comment: Don't start with induction before you learn more basic stuff, like direct proofs, proof by contraposition and proof by contradiction.